# Create msi using GNOME/msitools

Tags: windows-installer, centos7, msitools

I am running **Centos7** and my ultimate aim is to modify an existing `msi`(Microsoft Installer) file using https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/msitools...

but before doing that wanted to see whether I could extract an existing **msi** file and **recreate** the same(without any modification) using this `msitools` by doing following..

1. Extract existing **msi** table and file contents using tools like `**msidump**`, `**msiextract**`
2. Create the **msi** using `**msibuild**`

But I didn't get the expected msi file after second step, and got following error while trying to extract..
"`libmsi_record_get_stream: assertion 'LIBMSI_IS_RECORD (rec) failed'`". It is clear that I didnt create msi properly.

Can someone help me what should be the series of commands that should be used to just extract the existing `msi` and recreate the same using `msitools`.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Sounds complex. What is the scenario? Unless it is a technical exercise or a test of some sort?

Comment: Hey @SteinÅsmul,
The scenario is that I need to update existing .msi file with dynamic configuration and also include some files. So i need to know the exact set of commands I need to run to extract and modify and recreate the msi file.
Thanks.

Comment: Why does this need to be done on CentOS?

Comment: @SteinÅsmul,
Thats a requirement that can be changed